# width 100% is not yielding 100% of parent div. Grandchild contents are causing overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, browser

I'm facing the classic issue of overflowing text.

In summary: I'm trying to have the width of the top element (`grab_item--content`) propagate to the grandchild `template_panel--item` through a series of `width: 100%`. However, the first child (that class-less element with `draggable="false"`) is not respecting `width: 100%`.

[image: Overflowing Template]

[image: dom tree]

The text element itself (`template_panel_item--panelText`) is ready to handle the overflow with ellipsis.

```css
.template_panel_item--panelText--RuXFCGbr {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

However, the overflow logic isn't kicking in because `width: 100%` is not constrictive.

I assigned `width: 100%` to the first two layers of div's (`template_panel_item-panelText` and `panel_item--name`) so that they and their parent (`panel_item--info`) all have the same width. When I inspect them, all of these share the same width: `539.94px`.

Note: I didn't assign `width: 100%` to `panel_item--info` because it has siblings, and so it shouldn't hoard `100%` of the width. I suspect that this is part of the problem. However, when I change it to `width: 100%`, its width doesn't change.

[image: template_panel_item--panelText width]

[image: panel_item--info width]

```css
.panel_item--info--CWGaMv4e {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Going up the DOM tree, the first non-overflowing element is `grab_item--content`, which has a computed width of `304px`, right padding of `14px`, and `width: 100%`.

[image: grab_item--content width]

Its only child is an anonymous draggable div with `width: 100%`.

Note that it has a width of `627.94px` and not `539.94px` because of the fixed-width siblings of `panel_item--info` mentioned earlier.

[image: Draggable div width]

The infuriating part of this is that the draggable item's `width: 100%` isn't being ignored. It's simply yielding `100%` of `627.94px`. I verified this by changing its `width` property to `width: 50%` and seeing it change to `313.97px`.

[image: Draggle div at 50% width]

Isn't `width: 100%` supposed to give `100%` of the *parent's* width?  Therefore, shouldn't the draggable item's `width: 100%` be yielding `grab_item--content`'s width?!?!

This is on Chrome.

Comment: Try this : .template_panel_item--panelText--RuXFCGbr white-space: unset

Answer (score 0):

Just remove white-space: nowrap.
You can add "text-overflow: ellipsis;" instead "white-space: nowrap;"